# Working with internal npm modules

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, commonjs

I have a folder structure that looks something like this:

`Main
|package.json
|__node_modules
|__shared
   |__sh-utils
      |package.json
   |__sh-other
      |package.json
|__project_folder_a
|__project_folder_b`

project_folder_a and project_folder_b are actually a few levels deep but the point is that they both require dependencies defined in Main/package.json.

Main/package.json has a few normal registry dependencies but also a local folder dependency defined like so:

```
"sh-utils": "file:shared\\sh-utils"
```

This is an internal dependency that is not published to any registry.  Several files in project_folder_a and project_folder_b can now require it:

```
var Utils = require('sh-utils');
```

But I have not found a good way to propagate changes to sh-utils to its dependent projects.  So far I think these are my options:

1. Manually delete the sh-utils folder under Main/node_modules and then run "npm install" from Main
2. Run "npm install file:shared/sh-utils --force" from Main
3. Always remember to increment the version of sh-utils and then run "npm install" from Main

All of these seem cumbersome, especially for the other developers working in the same repository that will need to pick up the latest changes.  I also plan on having multiple small modules, so it really needs to be easy to update them all.  I like how easy it is to require the dependency once its there, but I'm wondering if it would just be easier to require it using a relative path:

```
var Utils = require('../../../sh-utils');
```

We're running gulp so would be open to something that takes advantage of that.